# Gradle не может загрузить проект Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, git, gradle

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при попытке клонировать проект на второй компьютер гредл в андроид студио постоянно выдает ошибку:
`Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)`

Проект клонировал с гита. Погуглив на англоязычном стаковерфлоу я нашел как один из вариантов [(ссылка)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652980/errorfailed-to-open-zip-file-gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt) в gradle-wrapper вручную вписать напрямую ссылку на zip гредла. Для меня это естественно не дало никакого эффекта.
Как альтернативу, пробовал перекинуть проект с флешки -эффекта так же не было. Очень надеюсь на помощь. Версии студий одинаковые.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что происходит, когда нажимаете на `Re-download dependencies ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Удалите вручную кэш зависимостей `gradle` (если чо, это и советует вам диагностика ошибки). Идете на `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.gradle\caches` и удаляете весь каталог (в Linux: `$HOME/.gradle/caches/`)
2. Касаемо `gradle-wrapper` - это актуально если вы используете его (что не факт) - в настройках Android Studio должен быть помечен флаг использовать `gradle-wrapper` или использовать бинарники `gradle` (я лично предпочитаю последнее)
3. Нелишним будет также и снести кэш Android Studio (`File->Clear caches`)

Comment: Спасибо большое!